# ClassNotFoundException when handling PDF files using iText in Jdeveloper

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, jdeveloper

I need your help in solving the following error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException

which is produced by running a simple `void` method to show the PDF file in the Jdeveloper. I added the itext jar file in the Libraries and the version which I am having is 5.5.6.

If I am writing a simple PDF, the method will be executed. However when I use the below code, it generates the error. The code is:

```
public class pdf {
    private StreamedContent streamedContent;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @PostConstruct     
    public void  CreatePDF() throws DocumentException, IOException {
      try{
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u064a\u0637\u064a"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);

        document.close();
        out.close();

        InputStream in =new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream)out).toByteArray());

                    streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "application/pdf");
                //-------
                Map<String, Object> session = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
                byte[] b = (byte[]) session.get("reportBytes");
                if (b != null) {
                    streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(b), "application/pdf");
                }         
      }
        catch (Exception e) {
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please be aware that a `ClassNotFoundException` doesn't mean that the class isn't present in the iText jar (it is) or in the CLASSPATH. It means that there is no ambiguous way to find the class. Knowing that the code works in other environments, I am pretty sure that you have *more than one* instance of iText in your CLASSPATH. You added (at least) two `DocumentException` classes and JDeveloper doesn't know which one to choose. Remove everything and start setting up your environment from scratch making sure you add iText only once.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks, But finally I found that the issue was from the DocumentException which is at the top in the method header. Once I removed it has solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iText WAR file is kept under the /lib folder and it has worked fine. The compatible version is iText 2.1.7 please refer to the Dependencies in the PrimeFaces Guide

Comment: Can you please clarify and tell the full path of /lib folder ? Is it directly in parent folder or ViewController\public_html\WEB-INF folder ?